# SQL Server 2012: trouble restoring database backup

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-restore

I tried running the following query to restore a database:

```
restore database myDatabase
from disk=
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLSERVER2012\MSSQL\Backup\myDatabase_backup_2012_06_20.bak' 
with replace, 

move 'myDatabase' to 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLSERVER2012\MSSQL\DATA\myDatabase',

move 'Analytics_log' to 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLSERVER2012\DATA\myDatabase_log.ldf'
```

And am getting the following error:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Directory lookup for the file
>   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11.SQLSERVER2012\DATA\myDatabase_log.ldf" failed with the
>   operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 File 'myDatabase_log' cannot be
>   restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11.SQLSERVER2012\DATA\myDatabase_log.ldf'.
>   Use WITH MOVE
>   to identify a valid location for the file.

For the first error, it seems like SQL Server cannot find the .ldf file. However, it is in that location and was listed in the results when I ran `restore filelistonly` on the .bak file.

Comment: @Shenaniganz, you were right! Thank you! If you write out your comment as a response I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your LDF file wasn't suppose to be copied to : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLSERVER2012\MSSQL\DATA\myDatabase_log.ldf ? ...Notice you're missing the MSSQL subfolder. What am saying is that LDF file path may be invalid.